# Binary excutable file reader and editor for the MiniPro TL866 Chip Programmer

Tags: windows, programming, editor, binary-data

I have a MiniPro TL866 programmer which uses binary files.

I would like to be able to open, read, edited and create new binary files which the MiniPro can work with. I have looked on the internet, but I am not sure if the ones I found will do what I need, or if the files are safe to download.

Can anyone suggest a free binary file editor, for Windows, that I can down load and do what I need?

Comment: Notepad++ can probably do it

Answer (score 2):

> I have a MiniPro TL866 programmer which uses binary files.

Many other things use binary files as well, e.g. Word files (.DOC) are binary, Windows Executables (.EXE) are binary and Linux Executables as well (ELF fomrat). The point is: there is no "the binary format", there are thousands.

And each of these binary formats has it's own, very specific editor. DOC files can be edited with Word, EXE files are not edited at all, they are generated by a compiler and so are ELF files.

Of course there are generic programs for editing binary files. Typically they are called HEX editor. But trust me, you don't want to edit a DOC file with such an editor.

So, the first thing is to find out exactly what binary format you're talking about.

> create new binary files which the MiniPro can work with.

Let's face the facts: you have a programmer. A programmer writes a program into some Flash memory or EEPROM. Therefore the binary file format is some sort of executable.

You would not "edit" executables, you would generate them from source code.

A programmer might be able to program many different chips. E.g. the MiniPro TL866 is able to program the ATMEGA328P. That chip is basically what's on an Arduino.

For a good software recommendation, we now need to know which chip exactly you're gonna use.

If it is the ATMEGA328P, you could use the [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software). If it's something else, e.g. the Texas Instruments MSP430, you might need [Code Composer Studio](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti_de/tools-software/ccs.page).

So, finally, I cannot give you an exact software recommendation, but a process recommendation:

1. Check which chips are supported by the programmer
2. Decide for a chip, based on your needs like RAM, MHz, etc.
3. Find a compiler for that chip
4. Find an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) which supports the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

[SRECORD](http://srecord.sourceforge.net) does file conversions between many formats use by programmers - some are plain ascii.
[Hexedit](http://www.hexedit.com) is powerful.
[Hex-Works Online Editor](https://hex-works.com/eng) might be easy